# Django Forms: Force the user to select one checkbox only at a time

Tags: django, django-forms

I am using Django forms to display checkboxes on my webpage as following:

```
class Myform(forms.Form):
    colors = forms.MultipleChoiceField(widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple, choices=COLORS)
```

and it is working pretty well.

**My question is:: how to force the user to select only one checkbox at a time?**

My code allows the user to select multiple checkboxes at the same time.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use [`ChoiceField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/forms/fields/#choicefield) instead of [`MultipleChoiceField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/forms/fields/#multiplechoicefield):

```
class MyForm(forms.Form):
    colors = forms.ChoiceField(choices=COLORS)
```

This will let the user to select **only one** `color` from your `COLORS` choices.

Comment: However that's not a checkbox

Answer (score 0):

One checkbox only at a time means that you are looking for a radio selection, i.e. use `RadioSelect` in the widget field.

```
class Myform(forms.Form):
    colors = forms.MultipleChoiceField(widget=forms.RadioSelect, choices=COLORS)
```

(untested)

I came across the same question while making a form with a many-to-many relation. This is when a multiple choice becomes practical. And if you need one and only one, then the radio selector is what you need.

Example where attendees have a m2m relation with trainings:

```
class attendeeForm(ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Attendee
        fields = '__all__'


    trainings = forms.ModelChoiceField(
        queryset=Training.objects.all(),
        widget=forms.RadioSelect,
    )
```

Answer (score -2):

class MyForm(forms.Form): 
    colors = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(choices=COLORS)

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited short-term help.  A proper explanation [would greatly improve](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) its long-term value by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions.  Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.